# how can i avoid spaces that come at the bottom of screen when resizing window? How to make the space same for all sizes of window?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers, navbar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .navbar-custom { 
            background-color:rgb(128 128 128 / 18%); 
            height:48px;
            width:100%
  }
  .close{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  h5{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0
 }
 html, body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 right:0;
  padding-right: 0px!important;
  margin-right: 0px!important; 
  width: 100vw; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 .row row-cols-1{
     width: 100%;
     right: 0;
 }
 .img-fluid{
     max-width: 100%;
     height : auto;
 }
 .btn btn-primary{
     width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 48%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
 }
 
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom ">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo1" alt="logo" style="width:50px;">
  </a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button type="button" class="close " aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
    </li>
</ul> 
</nav>  
<div class="container-fluid "> 
<h5><b>Do you have Fever above 101.4?</b></h5>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <img src="fever.png" class="img-responsive center-block d-block mx-auto mt-5" alt="logo" style="width:200px;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
    
    <div class="row row-cols-1  mx-2 ">
        
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  mt-5  ">Yes,I do</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  mt-1">No, I don't</button>

</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am experiencing a gap (space) below buttons when i'm resizing the window in vertical manner, the gap increases as i vertically upsize the window, it takes a space, i have tried different techniques including margin bottom, but didn't accomplish what i want to be, kindly suggest a solution which includes bootstrap 4. Thanks
moreover i want to center align the image on ipad such that is aligned on iphone screens

here the gap is increased

[image]

here the gap is decreased

[image]

i want to fill the gap below screen so that the image comes at center

[image]

just like it comes at center on iphone screens

[image]

Comment: have you tried @media only screen and (min-width:363px) and (max-width:400px) {} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `fixed-bottom` to your last div

like this:

```
  <div class=" fixed-bottom row row-cols-1  mx-2 ">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  mt-5  ">Yes,I do</button>
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary  mt-1">No, I don't</button>

  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: i have some more issue, can you please re read my question? @Themodmin

Comment: I hav some more issue , can you please see my question again? @Mansi

Comment: my pleasure, could you mark my answer as a solution, where are your other questions? @Syed Zeyad

Comment: i have a new question please answer it  " I want to take an input and use it as a parameter of a function in javascript"  @Themodmin